# VBA Code Efficiency - excel Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code I am running below, which works fine.

**Problem**: Is there are more effieicnt way to write this code? (Short)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D24")) Is Nothing Then
              Sheet2.Range("D24") = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    End If
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D20")) Is Nothing Then
              Sheet2.Range("D20") = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D25")) Is Nothing Then
              Sheet2.Range("D25") = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    End If
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D27")) Is Nothing Then
              Sheet2.Range("D27") = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    End If
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D28")) Is Nothing Then
              Sheet2.Range("D28") = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D30")) Is Nothing Then
              Sheet2.Range("D30") = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D31")) Is Nothing Then
              Sheet2.Range("D31") = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D32")) Is Nothing Then
              Sheet2.Range("D32") = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

Comment: You could store the address D20, D24, D25.. in an array.  Then loop over the array.

Comment: This should have been posted in codereview rather than here as the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, the text is not on the same sheet, this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Intersect(Target, Range("D20,D24,D25,D27,D28,D30,D31,D32")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'Cancel=True
Sheet2.Range(Target.Address).Value = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, without using Intersect:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Or .Column = 5 Then
            Select Case .Row
                Case 20, 24, 25, 27 To 28, 30 To 32

                    Application.EnableEvents = False

                    .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username")
                    .Value2 = .Value2 & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

                    Application.EnableEvents = True

            End Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Comment: I like that, it is more elegant than mine (and more efficient?).

Comment: I like that it works well. Just one more question. how do i apply this code to both column 4 & 5? @paulbica

Comment: @James - I updated it to `If .Column = 4 or .Column = 5 Then`

Comment: @SJR - yours is short, and explicit as well (mine is a bit more efficient because it checks the column first)